# sizeof(struct), sizeof(string), sizeof(array)

Tags: c, sizeof

I am confused as to what the `sizeof` function returns.

Suppose I enter the following into a program for `sizeof`, and this is what is returned:

```
sizeof(char) ==  1
sizeof(int) == 4
sizeof(float) == 4
sizeof(long) ==  8
sizeof(double) == 8
sizeof(void *) == 8
```

`sizeof Pointer` is 8.
So if I `malloc` a long array:

```
long *array = (long *)malloc(64)
```

Would this `sizeof()` inserted into the `malloc` of my long array be equivalent?

```
long *array = (long *)malloc(8*sizeof(long))
```

Now if I have a struct:

```
typedef struct treenode {
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
    void *content;
} Treenode;
```

And I run `sizeof(Treenode)`, do I add all the elements of the struct together?

> Pointer + Pointer + void * = 8 + 8 + 8 = 24

I tried running this in a program, however I get `sizeof(Treenode)` to return 12.

I am also wondering why when I create a new struct like this:

```
typedef struct country {
    char city[40];
    int population;
    int rank;
}
```

and try to `malloc(sizeof(country *))` only 8 bytes are allocated instead of the bytes of the struct.

Finally when I do `sizeof("Korea")`, why is my return value 6 and not 5? Should it not be 5 because there are only 5 chars in the string?

Comment: What is the definition of `Pointer`? BTW all of your questions have been answered multiple times here on SO. You should be able to find them.

Comment: You are missing ***A LOT*** of very basic concepts of C. For example, the fact that the size of a pointer is not the same as the size of its pointed object. And that strings contain an extra 0-terminator. You should first familiarize yourself with the fundamentals of the language before trying to do advanced stuff (like dynamic memory management).

Comment: Note that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Please read the help text on how to ask question here, again: don't ask several questions in one go, take more care in the formulation your question and search the site before asking.

Answer (score 2):

I will address each question separately:

- These are equivalent in the context you have described

  ```
  long *array = (long *)malloc(64)
  long *array = (long *)malloc(8*sizeof(long))
  ```

  However, this is not necessarily correct on all machines (if say on one machine a long is 16 bytes), therefore this code is not portable. You should only ever use the second method which is portable.
- I'm not sure why the size is claiming to be 12 - Sorry. (are you sure **all** pointer's sizes are 8?)
- while a `country` struct may be very large, a pointer to a `country` is just a pointer and as such it's size is in your case 8.
- In C strings are null terminated so that a string with five letters has a trailing null which is presumably part of the string's size.

Answer (score 1):

1. If `sizeof(Treenode)` is 12, then you are not using 64-bit pointers/memory.  If you got different results elsewhere (`sizeof(void *) == 8`) then you must have different targets.
2. `sizeof(country *)` is the size of a pointer to a `country`, that is -- the same as any other pointer.  Use `malloc(sizeof(country))` instead.
3. `sizeof("Korea")` includes the size of the string's null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

It is all matter of which architecture you are using.
on 32 bit, each pointer size is 4 bytes.
on 64 bit each pointer size is 8 bytes.

So if you run the following code:

```
long *array = (long *)malloc(64) ;
```

and the following code:

```
long *array = (long *)malloc(8*sizeof(long))
```

it would be the same on 64-bit but not in 32 bit.

`malloc(sizeof(country *))` allocates only 8 bytes because `(country *)` is type of a pointer (pointer to your country struct) and each pointer is 8 bytes long in 64-bit.